# How to add Fancybox to Shopify theme for videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, shopify

I'm making customizations to our Shopify theme (`Launchpad-star`) and noticed that, according to Shopify, [it doesn't natively support](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/colors-and-images/add-a-lightbox-to-all-images#prerequisites) Fancybox/Lightbox functionality for popups (images, videos, etc.). The store has already gone live with this theme, which has been customized, so switching to another theme is going to be challenging.

What's puzzling is that the Shopify documentation says,

`You can find out if your theme uses one [i.e., Lightbox, Fancybox, etc.], by going to a product page on your storefront and clicking on your main product image. If the image opens up in a centered box on the screen with the background dimmed, then you have a lightbox.`

The `Launchpad-star` theme's doesn't support this feature; however, when you view the page source of the shop, you see the Fancybox JavaScript library included (toward the bottom of the page):

```
<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0788/8735/t/2/assets/jquery.fancybox.js?16031678601526205939" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Does the `Launchpad-star` theme support Fancybox? If so, how? Can it support videos? We'd like to have the user click an image that then pops up a YouTube video.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Alex, did you find the answer to adding Fancybox to a theme?  I'm in the same boat.

Comment: No, @GaryM. Ended up using the Blueimp Gallery (https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md) instead, which works well with the Bootstrap files. It also supports videos and is responsive. Go here and look under the "Press" tab of the "Our Story" section: http://www.mimijumi.com/. If you view the page source, you'll see how it was included in the `HEAD` tag from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com. Then look in the source toward the end of the page for the `DIV` with ID `blueimp-gallery`. To have an image anchor pop up in the gallery, I use `data-gallery="#blueimp-gallery"` attribute.